# Can QGIS preserve layers when exporting a PDF?

Tags: qgis, pdf, layers, illustrator

I saw this posted about a year ago ([Can QGIS preserve layers when exporting to PDF?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7078/can-qgis-preserve-layers-when-exporting-to-pdf)) but figured it was worth asking again -- is this possible? My usual workflow with ArcGIS is to export to AI then edit the layers that way, is there some way to do that from QGIS? Now I just get everything in one huge layer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

See if this helps with the Illustrator part of your question:
 [Losing large portions of elevation contours from QGIS to PDF](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/26219/6725)

Short answer on QGIS layers to PDF layers support, not yet. My guess would be some form of support might show up by way of the [GDAL/OGR providers](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/tree/master/src/providers).

While the version 2 [GDAL driver](http://gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html) and [OGR driver](http://gdal.org/ogr/drv_pdf.html) have model-tree layer support for writing PDFs, it's not the same as 'regular' PDF layers.

*Sample of Model-Tree (not produced with GDAL/OGR)*

[image]

The GDAL driver appears to have support for layering an OGR data source over a raster layer (see OGR_DATASOURCE).

Here is some recent discussion on the subject:
[GDAL - Dev - [gdal-dev] Geospatial PDF with OGR_DATASOURCE](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Geospatial-PDF-with-OGR-DATASOURCE-tp4978717.html)

And some discussion on regular PDF layer support:
[GDAL - Dev - [gdal-dev] PDF selective layer sample wanted](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-PDF-selective-layer-sample-wanted-tp4547019p4549060.html)

There are other libraries, like [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) and [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/), but I don't know if anyone is integrating them with QGIS.

Comment: The GeoPDF support is now included in GDAL 1.11 for vector and raster data, but QGIS is not yet able to use it. It can only export a single raster layer to PDF.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to export it as svg using the simple [svg plugin](http://www.duif.net/qgis/simplesvg/). It keeps layers intact. Then Import the svg in AI. You could then save as PDF from AI if that is your final format.

http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/simplesvg/

Comment: I know this was forever ago, but I tried that and it put everything into one layer. This was using the print composer, I can't see how to export it otherwise.

Comment: Same problem with QGIS 3.0