# Vector objects "merged" in PDF with QGIS

Tags: qgis, illustrator

When I create a PDF file with QGis and open it in Adobe Illustrator, I cannot select the polygons one by one but only all together... See picture below
[image] 
With a PDF exported with another GIS software, in Adobe Illustrator, I can select the polygons one by one (so a publishing compagny can change the colors of each polygons)... See picture below
[image]
Is there a way to export PDF with QGis in order to be able to select the polygons one by one with Adobe Illustrator (or other publishing software...) ?

Comment: I don't think QGIS exports a layered PDF. Have you tried exporting as SVG and then opening that in AI / Inkscape? Check http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26814/can-qgis-preserve-layers-when-exporting-a-pdf and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7078/can-qgis-preserve-layers-when-exporting-to-pdf

Comment: Shortcuts in Illustrator CTRL+A then Shift+Ctrl+G is Ungroup

Comment: To ungroup the objects of the PDF file produces by QGis, it's not so easy with Illustrator (right click -> ungroup is greyed out...), the way I found to ungroup my PDF file in Illustrator is to use a script (open PDF with AI then Crtrl + F12): forums.adobe.com/thread/456042 it may help somebody one day...

Answer (score 1):

The paths are grouped in the PDF. You just need to "ungroup" them in Illustrator. Select the group, then right click and from the popup menu choose "Ungroup". You may need to do this a few times if the objects are inside nested groups, but eventually you'll be able to select them individually.

Alternatively, in Illustrator you can double-click a group to "isolate" it and work within that group. You would then be able to individually select members of the group (note that again, if groups are nested you may need to keep double-clicking until you enter the appropriate child group).

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! The aim was not to use illustrator (we have only one license for 10 people...) but if there is no other way to do...

Comment: Ok, in that case your question is very badly worded!

Comment: Try Inkscape as a free alternative to AI! The Ungroup functionnality is also available there...

Comment: To ungroup the objects of the PDF file produces by QGis, it's easy with Inkscape, but less easy with Illustrator (right click -> ungroup is greyed out...), the way I found to ungroup my PDF file in Illustrator is to use a script (open PDF with AI then Crtrl + F12): https://forums.adobe.com/thread/456042 it may help somebody one day...